# Empty Objects in a Vector of Objects vs NULL/nullptr in a Vector of Pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, vector, null

I'm trying to create a sort of entity/component system where the only thing identifying an entity is an index to vectors of components.

This is supposed to be an implementation of sorts of the so called Entity Component System. It is for a game I'm developing.

There is, for example, a vector of sprite components and a vector of health components and the same index on both of them is a part of the same entity. I.e. spriteComponents[0] is part of the same entity as healthComponents[0].

The problem I have is that not all entities will have all types of components. This means that I'll have to push some sort of empty/null on the vectors whose component type the entity does not have to retain the integrity of the index = entity id system.

I.e. entity 1 (index 1) does not have a spriteComponent so spriteComponents[1] should be some sort of empty/null.


For example:

With empty objects/null pointers:
ComponentType1: [x][x][x]
ComponentType2: [x][0][x]

Without:
ComponentType1: [x][x][x]
ComponentType2: [x][x]

Without them the indexes will not work correctly.

Now I had two options in mind and both should work but I'm wondering which is the better way:

```
//Option 1:
std::vector<SpriteComponent> spriteComponents;

/*Add empty object to retain index = entity system
when entity does not have a particular component*/

spriteComponents.push_back(SpriteComponent());

//Option 2:
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SpriteComponent>> spriteComponents;

/*Add nullptr to retain index = entity system
when entity does not have a particular component*/

spriteComponents.push_back(nullptr);
```

As I understand it, option 1 would have the advantage of the objects being contiguous in memory but using empty objects seems suboptimal. Is this still preferable to using pointers where I can simply use nullptr/NULL?

Of course if there is a better alternative I'm open to suggestions.

EDIT:
-I was planning on entities not being actual objects, i.e. an entity is simply an index to the vectors. This is so that later on systems such as drawing can simply iterate through the vector containing the sprite components without caring whose sprites they are.

This should then be rather efficient as they are right next to each other in memory whereas in a system where Entity would be a class containing spriteComponent and healthComponent etc. The iteration would be drastically less efficient (or so I understand.) as the similar components could possibly be nowhere near each other in memory.

Actually having the entities exist as an object containing only the necessary indexes could be a workable solution. Then I could also have them contain a single number that tells what components it actually has and doesn't have.

-Components will not be shared between entities.

-healthComponent is just an example of a component but it would contain information about the health of the entity and information affecting health (healthpoints, armorclass etc.) I am considering having them simply be structs (components.)

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you put sprite and health in a struct?

Comment: More context about your game could help us advise on the design. For example, will several object instances share the same component data? What is a Health component?

Comment: Entities may have index for each components (so you can iterate over your component without holes).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/libs/optional/doc/optional.html)